# MySQL, checking if any row of a related table matches a value and remove that row from the results

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users, I then have a table of purchases, with many purchases per user.

I want to select all users who have not purchased a given product.

What I am struggling with understanding is: how for each user I check if that users purchases matches the select, and then how I exclude those user from the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easily done by a simple `SELECT` Statement, a join and a subselect. My Examplequery will return you every User that hasn't bought a specific item.

```
SELECT DISTINCT User.Id, User.Username 
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Purchases ON User.Id = Purchase.UserId
WHERE 
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(User.Id)
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Purchases ON User.Id = Purchase.UserId
WHERE Purchase.ItemId = ParameterItemId) = 0
```

The `DISTINCT` in the query will make sure that there is no double entries.
Since you haven't given us any exmaples how your tables look like, I can only give you this pseudocode. It may not work on the first try and should only help you understand how a join and a subselect works.

To learn more about a `JOIN`, feel free to look it up on [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) documentation. To see more examples for a subselect, please see [this](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery).